# Data retrieval in Firebase for Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve my data from Firebase Database. My Firebase Database structure is like this:

```
 firebase-root:
user:
     uid:
user2:
     uid:
user3:
     uid:
```

-- and so on. I want to retrieve the data and display the data in a textview. Currently, I'm trying to display the data in a toast, because I currently don't have that much data. The code that I'm using is:

```
public void retData(View view){
        myref.child("User").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                String groupNames = (String) snapshot.getValue();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),groupNames,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

This function is always called when the user presses the button. But I'm not getting the data, instead I'm getting a toast (a black coloured toast) without any text. Kindly help.

Comment: have you checked this https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html. Do you have a POJO class?

Comment: your "groupNames" is empty thats why you are getting black toast without any text. Check it once.

Comment: thank you it worked.@HeenaArora